# IN clause of mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have Table Hotel. There is multiple column but i want apply In clause on filter column but it occurs error. Give solution.

The query is

```
Select * 
from hotel inner 
join hoteltype on hotel.type_id=hoteltype.id inner 
join area on hotel.area_id=area.id 
where area.area='Shivaji Chowk' 
and type='Restaurant' 
and filter In(Deals,Online Payment available,Pure Vegetarian );
```

Error is

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Payment available,Pure Vegetarian ) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: filter In('Deals','Online Payment available','Pure Vegetarian' );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below-

```
Select * from hotel inner join hoteltype on hotel.type_id=hoteltype.id 
inner join area on hotel.area_id=area.id 
where area.area='Shivaji Chowk' and type='Restaurant' and filter In
('Deals','Online Payment available','Pure Vegetarian');
```

Comment: it works but result not found. Filter column contain following data in each row  1.Preorder available,Deals,Pure Vegetarian,Non - Vegetarian,                                            2.Preorder available,Deals,Pure Vegetarian,Non - Vegetarian,                                                           3.Preorder available,Deals,Pure Vegetarian,     Now i want to display hotel 1,2,3 based on filter plz give solution